# A container allowing quickly listing items with keys in a given interval (GUI organisation)

Tags: search, user-interface, data-structures, graphics, game-engine

I'm trying to create a simple GUI for a 2D-game. There is a very long horizontally scrollable "room" and a lot of "objects" in it. Each "object" is a rectangle with a custom painting algorithm and may be created or erased.

What I need to figure out is which objects are on screen using my scrolling coordinates. There are a plenty of objects, so using linked list is probably ineffective. On the other hand, the objects are normally not moving.

My consideration to deal with this is to use a data container (a kind of tree?) with a quick interval-finding algorithm. However, I couldn't find any of these. Can you give me some tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) might help here.

As an alternative, if your objects have a small deviation in size or a smallish maximum size, consider simply having a sorted array (on which you can use binary search) or a [binary search tree (BST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), and then you can simply index by the left-most position of an object, and, when querying, find the interval starting at the left-most position minus the maximum size up to the right-most position. BST implementations often allows one to traverse the tree in order, from any given node, or allow for range queries.